# TikZ, arrows.meta: How to bring an arrowhead in direction of the path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I use 
`% \usetikzlibrary{bending}` 
`>={Stealth[length=3.5pt, width=2pt, inset=1pt, bend]}` 
but this has no effect at the red arrowhead.

Is there something I can do to "bend / slope" the red arrowhead?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
 \usetikzlibrary{bending}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em, y=1em, 
>={Stealth[length=3.5pt, width=2pt, inset=1pt, bend]},
No/.style={->, thin, font=\sffamily\tiny, blue, inner sep=0.5pt, very near start},
]
\draw[No] (140:1.2) -- +(0.6,0.05) node[No, above]{1};
\draw[No] (163:0.9) -- +(0.6,0.05) node[No, above]{2};

\draw[No, red, rounded corners=3] (200:0.6) -- ++(-0.3,-0.3) -- ++(0.3,-0.3) node[below]{bad};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a Ti*k*Z library called `bending`. Is that what you want?

Comment: First of all `\usetikzlibrary{bending}` has an effect, and if you want to bend the arrows use `>={Stealth[length=3.5pt, width=2pt, inset=1pt,bend]}`.

Comment: I do not come to a solution with `bend`...

Comment: How does this comment help? You have received two comments telling you what to do. Your code does not use `bend`, so the arrow head is not bent. Rather than updating your question and trying out what others have suggested, you just place this comment, the interpretation of which is not clear.

Comment: edit......................................................

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat `rounded corners` is only applied when translating the soft path into specials, but `bend` is applied before that.

Comment: @HenriMenke According to this statement shouldn't the following intersection be off? `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[name path=arc,rounded corners=1cm] (0,0) |- (2,2);
 \draw[name path=line]  (1,1) -- (-1,3);
 \path[name intersections={of=arc and line}] 
  (intersection-1) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat What do intersections have to do with `bend`?

Comment: @HenriMenke Nothing but your above comment. " rounded corners is only applied when translating the soft path into specials". This suggests that the rounded corner path is not "known" to Ti*k*Z, and my example shows that this is not the case. The true statement is that it is simply not covered because it is not a standard Bezier curve for which the curvilinear transformations are designed.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat No, my statement is correct, but the `intersections` library actually picks the `rounded corners` out of the soft path to account for them.  Search for `\pgfprocessround` in `pgflibraryintersections.code.tex`.  It should be possible to implement the same for `bending` as well if there is an eager contributer who wants to do this.

Comment: @HenriMenke I agree with the last statement but wonder what the purpose of your first comment was. It reads as if one could not make it work because Ti*k*Z does not have the path information. If you are saying that one could make it work in principle, we have an agreement.

Comment: @HenriMenke BTW, it is certainly not the case the `intersections` are special in this regard. The path information is also there for decorations, e.g. `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[rounded corners=1cm,postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,
  mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 5pt
      with {\fill[red] circle[radius=1pt]; }}}] 
   (0,0) -- ++ (0,1) |- ++ (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Decorations actually also treat rounded corners separately.  See here for a survey of where it is specially treated as well: http://dpaste.com/00996C9 (expires in 10 days)

Comment: @HenriMenke Well, OK. Anyway, the bottom-line is that one can make arrows bend around rounded corners in principle. but this is not implemented at this point, and won't be likely implemented in the near future.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Currently `bend` uses some special coordinates that are stored during soft path construction.  To treat rounded corners correctly it would have to process the entire soft path (and probably be put later in the path construction routine).  That's a lot of work which I can currently not invest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the rounded corners seem to get ignored by `bending`. This is because how bending works.<sup>1</sup> To understand this, look at the discussion in sections **TikZ Library bending** on p. 204 of the pgfmanual v3.1.5, and section **TikZ Library curvilinear** on p. 1165. However, you can construct a very similar smooth path for which it works.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
 \usetikzlibrary{bending}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1em, y=1em, 
>={Stealth[length=3.5pt, width=2pt, inset=1pt, bend]},
No/.style={->, thin, font=\sffamily\tiny, blue, inner sep=0.5pt, very near start},
]
\draw[No] (140:1.2) -- +(0.6,0.05) node[No, above]{1};
\draw[No] (163:0.9) -- +(0.6,0.05) node[No, above]{2};

\path  (200:0.6) coordinate (p1) -- ++(-0.3,-0.3)  coordinate (p2)
 -- ++(0.3,-0.3)  coordinate (p3);
\draw[No, red] plot[smooth,samples at={1,2,3},tension=1.6] (p\x)
node[below]{not bad};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub><sup>1</sup>This is *not* parallel to the fact that we cannot access the outlines of thick curves. The latter is because the thick line is drawn with the viewer, i.e. by specials. We have perfect access to the coordinates of paths with rounded corners in decorations and intersections. The point is that rounded corners are just not supported by bending.</sub>